# Does Vx & Vy calculations for aircraft with fixed pitch props account for lower power output at lower rpm?

Tags: vx, vy

In an aircraft with a fixed pitch prop, engine rpm can change significantly (increases) as airpeed increases. Since the power output of the engine increases as rpm increases, clearly the calculated Vx & Vy speeds should take this into consideration, especially on aircraft with a wide range of speeds between takeoff/climb and cruise speed, and have a "*cruise*" prop mounted (designed to reach maximum engine power/rpm at or near cruise airspeed). Do the published Vx & Vy speeds in aircraft POHs take this into consideration? And how should a pilot who has changed his/her prop modify a published Vx or Vy speed to reflect this?

Comment: "Do the published Vx & Vy speeds in aircraft POHs take this into consideration?" -- I should hope so!  It's hard to imagine why this would be doubted--

Comment: How can they know what engine, or what prop, is gping to be installed on the plane? In the experimental world, every plane is unique, owner/builders are free to install almost any engine/propeller combination they wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the different amount of power that can be developed at different airspeeds is taken into account. If it were not, then Vy would always be equal to the minimum sink speed when the engine is off. Changing the prop changes the shape of the power curve and hence changes both Vx and Vy.

With a new prop, you can simply test your climb performance at different airspeeds. With a cruise prop you would expect the airspeeds to be higher than for a climb prop.

Comment: As I surmised.  So for those of us with experimental aircraft, (canards in my case), where we get to choose what prop (and what engine) we install, we really need to perform flight testing to determine what Vx and Vy speeds to use.

Comment: @CharlesBretana You'd need that flight testing in any case. Every experimental aircraft is unique. Even with the same engine and prop, there's no guarantee the V speeds are exactly the same. Changing the prop and the engine just makes the difference larger. [AC 90-89C](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1041650) suggests that determining Vx and Vy should be done during the 11th to 20th hour of flight testing during part of the overall evaluation of its properties in slow flight.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I did not build or flight test my aircraft, I purchased it from the builder, who (according to the FAA paperwork), did, so I was misled by the published Vx & Vy speeds in my aircrafts POH. As I had never thought about the effect of the prop on these speeds, so seeing them published there gave me erroneous impression that they were applicable to the aerodynamic characteristics of the airframe itself, and not dependent on the prop and engine.